# What is the reason I can't execute the code below?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$greeting = 'hi';

echo 'hi' $greeting;
?>
```

I know that the above works when string interpolation is used such as `echo "hi $greeting";` but if the code works individually as in `echo 'hi'` and `echo $greeting` I don't understand why the I get an error when the code is combined to be `echo 'hi' $greeting;` as I illustrated above.

Comment: Concatenate your string and variable.

Comment: I would like to know why it won't work instead of using a concatenation to make it work.

Comment: @Robert I recommend to do some research on the language and its' syntax. You can't just guess how it's supposed to work. It's the same reason `foo("hi" "hi")` is invalid in any language.

Comment: You're trying to echo a string. To add a variable to that echo you need to concatenate.

Comment: If you would still go with this you can do that with brackets like echo 'hi {$greeting}';

Comment: @aldrin27 Ah! another way to do it!Thanks!!

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks! you are right, my tendency as a rookie in this language was to try to make up rules bymyself and wonder why something wouldn't work this way. But just like grammar in English, there are certain rules and its not smart to ask why this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that isn't valid code. You need to concatenate the strings if you want to do it like that:

```
echo 'hi' . $greeting;
```

Comment: Would there be a technical reason though? I understand that concatenation is necessary here but why?

Comment: Because thats just how PHP works. `echo` is just a PHP function, and by doing `echo 'hi' $greeting;` you are just putting two expressions next to each other and not telling PHP how they interact with each other.

Comment: Additionally, `echo` can take multiple strings without concatenation by passing them as separate parameters: `echo 'hi', $greeting;`

Comment: Ah! interesting it works when there is a commna between! Thanks!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your code's this part

```
echo 'hi' $greeting;
```

to

```
echo 'hi'.$greeting;
```